# How do I fix code not being ignored by phpcs in VSCode

Tags: vscode-extensions, phpcs

I'm trying to (temporarily) ignore some errors about not using Nonces. I've tried using `// @codingStandardsIgnoreLine.` before the line, and I've tried using `// phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.NonceVerification.Missing.`, I'm still being notified of a nonce problem:

[image]

What have I done wrong? I'm using VSCode. I have PHPCS installed using composer, and the PHPCS (and -BF) extensions installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add `/Users/your-username/.composer/vendor/bin/phpcs` as part of the installation? I had a similar issue because I had added another username.

Also, make sure that the following line is at the root of your project in a terminal:

```
composer require --dev squizlabs/php_codesniffer
```

To ignore the line, you can alternatively type
`// phpcs:disable` and `// phpcs:enable` at the beginning and end of the line.

Comment: Thank you - ```composer require --dev squizlabs/php_codesniffer``` did the trick. I had changed git branches and I don't think the package file came with it... Either way, thanks, that did it.